# Xamarin.ios how to disable logs in release build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, syslog, nslog

How to disable all logs from being written in release mode including NSLog based logs as well.

Mobile app peneteration tools are basically able to find out NSLog being used.

In native iOS it is easy to do but in xamarin there is no way to disable this.

I couldn't find any compiler flag for disabling this.If I could find a compiler flag for this then I can input that in mtouch and fix the issue.

Any help is welcome

Comment: There is no compiler flag to disable output. This is up to your code not to output to the "log" in Release mode builds if that is your desire. You can use `Debug.WriteLine` as `System.Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @SushiHangover - I am not writing any logs but xamarin produces logs by itself and pentesting tools shows and NSlog is being used ...strange though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug.writeline is meant to be used in development build

I am 100% certain that there is debug flag part of your project
We saved this conversation. You'll see it soon in the Conversations tab in Skype for Business and in the Conversation History folder in Outlook.

Right click on the PCL project
choose options
choose compiler
In the configurations choose the configuration that you are using and see 
what you have got in Define symbols

Comment: Thanks for the steps